# call a component method from main vue app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, components

I'm super new to Vue and I'm trying to get into components.

Basically, I have the main script file with my new vue app (with a countdown function based on setInterval and in the same file a vue component( it's a stamina bar made with canvas) with width increasing and decreasing methods. Basically, I would like to decrease the bar width every second but I don't get how to call the methods declared in the component. I guess that when they are declared inside the component I could access them from everywhere, but I didn't find a proper solution ( I tried with `$refs` but it's not working)
Is there any way where I can call the `addWidth()` and `subWidth()` function from a method in my new Vue app?

thank you

this is the component

```html
    Vue.component('stamina', {
    template: '<div><canvas ref="stamina" style="height:25px;width:300px;" /></div>',

    data(){

        return {
            stamina_width:300,

            // vueCanvas: null
        }
    },
  
    methods: {

        drawStamina(){
             // clear canvas
            this.vueCanvas.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 50);

            // draw rect

            this.vueCanvas.rect(20,20, this.stamina_width, 100);

            //colorize with gradient

            var grd = this.vueCanvas.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 300, 0);
            grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
            grd.addColorStop(0.5, "orange");
            grd.addColorStop(1, "green");
            this.vueCanvas.fillStyle = grd;

            //fill the rect with gradient
            this.vueCanvas.fillRect(0, 10,this.stamina_width, 10); 
        },

        addWidth() {
            this.stamina_width += 20
            this.drawStamina()
        },
        subWidth() {
            this.stamina_width -= 20
            this.drawStamina()      
        }

    },

    mounted () {

        var ctx = this.$refs.stamina.getContext('2d');
        this.vueCanvas = ctx;
        var stam = this.stamina_width;

        var grd = this.vueCanvas.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 300, 0);
        grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
        grd.addColorStop(0.5, "orange");
        grd.addColorStop(1, "green");
        this.vueCanvas.fillStyle = grd;
        
        //fill the rect with gradient
        this.vueCanvas.fillRect(0,25,stam,25); 

    }
});


and this is the main vue

   
    var match = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
   
    methods:{
    //call the methods from component stamina
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Yes, you can call methods in child components, but I would highly suggest to reconsider your app design. Normally you wold not do such operations from main.js

Comment: The typical data flow in a Vue application is: *"props down, events up"*. Which means your main.js has a property which is passed down to the child. The child reads its value and reacts to changes. Anytime you want to change something in the child you don't call the child method, you change the parent property and the child reacts to that change. In turn, when you want the child to update the parent, you `$emit()` a custom event. Obviously, there are alternatives, but this is the typical data flow.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can call methods up/down of parent/child components. You may need to look at creating [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) and listen for them.

Another option I believe might be less complex is to consider using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

All of your `addWidth` and `subWidth` logic will reside in a centralized place this way. All of your components--no matter how nested can "subscribe" to these things (and modify them if needed).

Check out [actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html). You'll dispatch an action `addWidth` which sends it to Vuex. In your component that is responsible for rendering the stamina bar I would use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to watch for updates. Something like this:

```
computed: {
    barWidth() {
       return this.$store.getters["bar/width"];  // 20
    }
}
```

That is just a really rough example and will not likely be what you're looking for.

[VueSchool](https://vueschool.io/courses/vuex-for-everyone) has some nice (free) courses to help get you rolling with Vuex as well.

Comment: Most developers, especially the ones just starting with Vue, consider Vuex *more* complex, not less so. Unless they come from React ecosystem and are familiar with the Flux pattern. Don't get me wrong, I don't advocate against it. On the contrary, I think the sooner a developer learns it the sooner they are able to circumvent a lot of data/state design related problems which junior developers typically face. But advertising it as a *"less complex"* pattern is a bit misleading, to say the least.